# Geolocation Map view not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, geolocation, map

I have a SharePoint list with a geolocation field. No issues here. The list is my company's offices, and I am trying to create a map view of the list to show our offices in relation to each other, however when I try and create a map view I get the error "You must select exactly one geolocation column to display in this view."

I have unselected all of the columns and selected just one geolocation field. I have tried to select the geolocation field, as well as the 'Geolocation:Street' option. I have tried to select just one of these fields and one other column only in case somehow I magically have another geolocation field in there, but nothing is working - I get that error and can't save my map view.

The only thing I thought could be impacting this is the Bing Maps Key (referenced here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-map-view-for-the-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint). However in all of the documentation, even if I had one of these I wouldn't know what to do with it or how to get it in my site.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the article you linked, click on the link to "[Integrating location and map functionality in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/integrating-location-and-map-functionality-in-sharepoint)"

There you will find:

How to: Set the Bing Maps key at the web and farm level in SharePoint

SharePoint uses Bings Maps to render the map of the location. To be able to use the Bing Maps feature, you need to create a Bing Maps key and set the key at the web or farm level. The article shows the various ways you can set the key in SharePoint and when to choose which option. You see an error message on the map if you do not use a valid Bing Maps key or if a key is not set at the web that contains the list or at the farm level.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't clicked through all of the linked articles -whoops! I will look into this, thank you!